# LinkButton click event not firing in dynamic usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, webforms

On my main page view I have a linkbutton, a placeholder, and I register my usercontrol:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="vf" TagName="Headline" Src="~/Controls/Headline.ascx" %>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lbAddHeadline" runat="server" OnClick="lbAddHeadline_OnClick">+ Headline</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phAddTemplateControlsArea" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In the event of this link button I give my control an ID based on how many controls I have added to the page, I also set a command arg and link up a button click event, then I load them all to a panel.
When I click the button in the usercontrol, I want it to fire a method on my main page, RemoveItem_OnClick()

```
protected void lbAddHeadline_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Controls_Headline ctrl = (Controls_Headline)LoadControl("~/Controls/Headline.ascx");
    ctrl.ID = "MyCtrl_" + CMSSession.Current.AddedTemplateControls.Count;
    ctrl.Remove.CommandArgument = CMSSession.Current.AddedTemplateControls.Count.ToString();
    ctrl.RemoveEvent += new EventHandler(RemoveItem_OnClick);

    CMSSession.Current.AddedTemplateControls.Add((Control)ctrl);

    LoadControlsToPanel();
}

private void LoadControlsToPanel()
{
    PlaceHolder ph = accAddTemplates.FindControl("phAddTemplateControlsArea") as PlaceHolder;

    foreach (var ctrl in CMSSession.Current.AddedTemplateControls)
    {
        ph.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    }
}

public void RemoveItem_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = sender as LinkButton;
}
```

When the controls are added to the panel on the main page, I have overridden the OnInit method to preserve data in the usercontrol:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    PlaceHolder ph = accAddTemplates.FindControl("phAddTemplateControlsArea") as PlaceHolder;

    int counter = 0;

    foreach (UserControl ctrl in CMSSession.Current.AddedTemplateControls)
    {
        ctrl.ID = "MyCtrl_" + counter;
        ITemplateControl ictrl = ctrl as ITemplateControl;
        ictrl.Remove.CommandArgument = counter.ToString();
        ictrl.RemoveEvent += new EventHandler(RemoveItem_OnClick);
        counter++;
        ph.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    }

    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

As you can see, the usercontrol impliments a common interface that it, and other usercontrols will use so I can link up some of the common buttons

```
public interface ITemplateControl
{
    LinkButton Remove { get; set; }
    TextBox Label { get; set; }
    event EventHandler RemoveEvent;
}
```

This is the html for the usercontrol:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Headline.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_Headline" %>

<div class="headline">

    Headline Text:

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLabel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbRemove" runat="server" OnClick="lbRemove_OnClick">X</asp:LinkButton>

</div>
```

This is the codebehind of the usercontrol:

```
public partial class Controls_Headline : UserControl, ITemplateControl
{    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbRemove.Click += new EventHandler(lbRemove_OnClick);
    }

    public TextBox Label
    {
        get { return txtLabel; }
        set { txtLabel = value; }
    }

    public LinkButton Remove
    {
        get { return lbRemove; }
        set { lbRemove = value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler RemoveEvent;

    protected void lbRemove_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RemoveEvent != null)
        {
            RemoveEvent(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I click the lbRemove linkbutton that is located within the usercontrol, I expect it to call it's own method lbRemove_OnClick, and then call the delegate event I bound to in the OnInit method.

What happens every time I click the lbRemove linkbutton is it calls the OnInit method of the main page, and thats it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

Just directly bound the click event from the UC to the click event in the page.  I was overcomplicating it.

```
    protected void lbAddHeadline_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controls_Headline ctrl = (Controls_Headline)LoadControl("~/Controls/Headline.ascx");
        ctrl.ID = "MyCtrl_" + CMSSession.Current.AddedTemplateControls.Count;
        ctrl.Remove.CommandArgument = CMSSession.Current.AddedTemplateControls.Count.ToString();
        ctrl.Remove.Click += new EventHandler(RemoveItem_OnClick);

        CMSSession.Current.AddedTemplateControls.Add((Control)ctrl);

        LoadControlsToPanel();
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        PlaceHolder ph = accAddTemplates.FindControl("phAddTemplateControlsArea") as PlaceHolder;

        int counter = 0;

        foreach (UserControl ctrl in CMSSession.Current.AddedTemplateControls)
        {
            ctrl.ID = "MyCtrl_" + counter;
            ITemplateControl ictrl = ctrl as ITemplateControl;
            ictrl.Remove.CommandArgument = counter.ToString();
            ictrl.Remove.Click += new EventHandler(RemoveItem_OnClick);
            counter++;
            ph.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        }

        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```